# mysql_query update

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a script which runs when a user hits the 'reject' button on some terms.
When it runs it should revoke the access rights to the particular area, for some reason the script doesn't work- as in it doesn't update the MYSQL DB nor do I get die error.

```
$username =  $_SESSION["USER"]["Username"]; 

mysql_connect("x", "y", "z") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `SeceretArea`='Unauth' WHERE `Username`='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: As stated in the PHP manual for the `mysql_*` functions: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: It's for a small project and not a large scale website

Comment: if you run the update using mySQL command line or workbench, does it execute properly?

Comment: did you call `session_start()` to initialize the session on this script?

Comment: Is this small project going to be accessible from the internet?

Comment: `session_start()` is called yeah, and I'll give that ago @Bondye

Comment: UPDATE `users` SET `SeceretArea` .... do you mean "SecretArea" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ANSWER UPDATED TO SUM UP DEBUGGING PROCESS.**

If there is no error, then there are three possibilities as to why the database entry isn't happening:

- There is no entry in your table where the `USERNAME` column is equal to `$database`.
- There is no value being passed to `$database`.
- There is a value being passed to `$database`, but that value isn't being replaced into the query.

From my personal experience, `mysql_query()` doesn't necessarily substitute variable values in before executing the query. Create the query string first into a variable, then pass it to `mysql_query()`. Your current setup doesn't replace `$username` with its value. What you can do is this:

```
...
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `SeceretArea`='Unauth' WHERE `Username`='$username'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Apart from that, check your table to make sure that there is a row with the value you want in `USERNAME`. `var_dump()` your `$username` to see if it's the value that you intended.

Also, you really should consider switching to either `mysqli` or `PDO`. If you don't want to migrate to an object module, you can use `mysqli`'s procedural functions.

Comment: It does replace `$username` with its value.

Comment: @Bondye Does it? I've seen it not replace before. @Rsmithy Then the next step is to ask: does the value of `$username` exist in the database?

Comment: Humm it should do, it grabs the session username which the user logs in with, so for themselves to be be logged in their user would have to exist- let me check my DB out, I must have some error somewhere

Comment: If I replace `$username` with a username and run it... it works

Comment: Well, the lack of errors suggests that either the value of `$username` doesn't exist in your table, or that `$username` doesn't have a value. Try passing `$username = desired_value` instead of the session variable, where `desired_value` is the value that worked.

Comment: This works if ran with a username entered manually.. so something must be wrong at my end

Comment: What do you mean with "From my personal experience, mysql_query() doesn't necessarily substitute variable values in before executing the query.". Variable substitution is a language feature of PHP not a feature of `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @DioF I mean, I've had situations where doing something like `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table")` will query for the statement "SELECT * FROM $table" instead of replacing the table name. My fix? Putting the query into a variable and passing the variable itself to `mysql_query()`, as shown in my answer. It worked for me, I thought it might work for others.

Comment: @Palladium: Not when `$table` contains the value `$table`. See http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: @DioF I know what it *should* do, I'm saying I've had situations where it **didn't** do that, and my fix was literally just moving the statement outside `mysql_query()`. Or are you going to tell me that I'm making stories up for attention? Because that is essentially where you're going with this at this rate.

Comment: @Palladium: I won't. But it would be cool if you could reproduce it and report it as a bug on https://bugs.php.net/.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make sure you call `session_start();` at the top of your script. Without it, your `$username` variable will never get set.

Comment: `session_start();` is called at the start

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **$username** carries the session value you passed.

```
echo "$username";
```

Proceed to query only when you get it correct.

And also, make sure the field name of the table is correct. I noticed **SeceretArea** which possibly is **SecretArea** in your table.

Comment: I changed the fields names before asking.. on my DB it's actually called Area51 which matches the script

Comment: And what does `echo $_SESSION["USER"]["Username"];` print out?

Comment: That means, you are not getting any value in `$_SESSION["USER"]["Username"]`. You probably have problem while passing the session username.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your session. This is no database-relevant problem. I guess the referenced session does not hold this information. Can you check that?

Comment: Well the session is passed from the main website to another part and is reauthorised to see if you have the correct permissions... I'm thinking the problem is one authorises the username as their username and the other (The "secret" part)  it using the username session as the user ID

Comment: so my sloppy coding is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just a few thoughts:

- Is there an entry in the DB with the exact value for `UserName` you are WHEREing?
- Are you inside an uncommitted transaction?
- Does your SQL statement interfer with another table with the same name?